# Best string container: StringCollection, Collection<string>, List<string>, ArrayList, ..?

Tags: .net, list, collections, containers, ilist

What is the most suitable container just for strings holding in some array with non-predetermined upper boundary, which length is unknown on it's creation.

For simple code like:

```
var list = new SomeContainer(); // size is unknown
for()/foreach()/do()/while() // any loop
{
  list.Add(string);
}
```

Is it `StringCollection` as optimized Collection for string, or just `Collection<string>` or `List<string>` or `ArrayList` ? What is the different between them?

Comment: Related question concerning performance specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774374/performance-concern-stringcollection-vs-liststring

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For what you need, `List<string>` is probably the most versatile. `StringCollection` was handy in 1.1, when (without generics) you needed specific classes for typed collections. `Collection<string>` is handy if you want to subclass it to provide validation etc.

Either way, in 3.5, LINQ will provide lots of additional methods for them - but without LINQ, `List<T>` has more features (`Find`, `Sort`, etc)

Answer (score 15):

A `List<T>` would be the most efficient.

The `Collection<T>` class is just a wrapper for another type of list, the parameterless constructor initialises the `Collection<T>` with a `List<T>`.

An `ArrayList` is essentially the same as a `List<object>`, so you would have to cast the items to `String` when reading from it.

A `StringCollection` is just a type safe wrapper for an `ArrayList`.