# Which collection for storing unique strings?

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary

I'm looking for a collection just like `Dictionary(OF Key, Value)` but I don't actually need a key and value. Key itself is enough. So something like `Collection(Key)`. It shouldn't accept duplicate keys.

I've looked up couple of collections in .NET Framework but couldn't find what I want. Currently I'm abusing `Dictionary(OF String, String)` and setting Value as `Nothing` all the time.

Shall I just continue abusing Dictionary(OF T,T)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think what you want is a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) would work for this.  It lets you store a unique set of values, without "abusing" a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

List would be better than Collection as noted in this [semi-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669106/best-string-container-stringcollection-collectionstring-liststring-arraylist).

A hashset in 3.5 would be better still. What version of .net are you using?