# Using a Hashtable to store only keys?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which collection for storing unique strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692853/which-collection-for-storing-unique-strings)

I am currently using a Dictionary<string, bool> to store a list of unique identifiers.  These identifiers do not need to have any data associated with them - I am just using the Dictionary to be able to quickly check for duplicates.

Since I only need keys, and no values, is a Dictionary the way to go here, or is there another collection I don't know about that would be better suited?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692853/which-collection-for-storing-unique-strings

Comment: Should have mentioned that this is for Framework 2.0.  Dictionary it is then.  Maybe I can use a bool value for something :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

.NET 3.5 includes the `HashSet<T>` collection type, which sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 17):

[HashSet`<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Comment: Which is available in .NET 3.5 and later only.

Comment: @0xA3: But which you can easily use in .NET 2.0 by just copying these two mono classes into your code...  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mono/mono/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Collections.Generic/HashSet.cs and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mono/mono/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/HashPrimeNumbers.cs