# Why is this generic list not being saved in application settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, application-settings

I'm saving and loading various variables in my application settings file (Settings.settings). Saving/Loading variables such as `strings`, `Uris` and `DataTables` is *working correctly*.

When attempting to Save/Load a custom object `List<IterationFilter>`, the List is lost when the application is closed and reopened.  `List<IterationFilters>` becomes `null` when the application is reloaded... even though an `IterationFilter` was added to the List and saved.

**Saving a String (working correctly):**

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString = connectionString;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Saving a Generic List:**

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FilterList.Add(newFilter);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24938228/4449640), to create my List setting.  My .settings file looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot showing a settings file]

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public System.Collections.Generic.List<TFS_Extraction.IterationFilter> FilterList {
    get{
            return ((System.Collections.Generic.List<TFS_Extraction.IterationFilter>)(this["FilterList"]));
       }
    set{
            this["FilterList"] = value;
       }
}
```

**My IterationFilter class:**

```
namespace TFS_Extraction
{
[Serializable]
public class IterationFilter
{
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IterationFilter(string _operator, string _value)
    {
        Operator = _operator;
        Value = _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Crowcoder I should have made it clear that all my settings are scoped as "User".

Comment: Is the IterationFilter class serializable in any way? For example is it marked with the SettingsSerializeAs Attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TFS_Extraction.IterationFilter` has to be serializable. The class is required to have a public default constructor.

Comment: I added `[Serializable]` directly before my IterationFilter class definition, but the setting is still not being persisted

Comment: @Kyle Williamson try adding the default constructor  public IterationFilter() {...}

Comment: For XML serialization [Serializable] attribute is not necessary

Comment: Adding a default constructor to the `IterationFilter` class fixed my issue!  I tried removing `[Serializable]` and the List is still being saved.  If you can update your answer to include a default constructor... I can mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @Kyle Williamson No problem.