# Refresh wpf listbox when collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am using settings with a string collection in it.

I populate the listbox with the following binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding QuadStash, Source={StaticResource Settings}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

When I add a new string to the collection, the items in the listbox will not update.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the code behind?

Comment: This is how i add a new 
    Settings.Default.Collection.Add("STRING");
    Settings.Default.Save();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insofar as you did not provided the code that shows how you created the StaticResource I'll assume that you want to bind Settings directly from xaml.

### Bind Settings.Default from XAML

In the first instance, add XML namespace that is pointing to namespace where the Settings class is declared:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WpfSettings.Properties"
```

Then you can bind your collection from settings as follows:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Collection}"
```

Since you bind directly to the collection that is declared directly in settings, WPF is not aware of collection updates if it does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. To solve this problem you could create `ObservableCollection` in settings.

### Create ObservableCollection in settings

[Open settings in XML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2890271) and add new setting as follows:

```
<Setting Name="Collection" Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection&lt;System.String&gt;" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

Then add the default value in settings editor ([source](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/06/use-a-string-collection-setting-in-c/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

In the end, it might look like this:

```
<Setting Name="Collection" Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection&lt;System.String&gt;" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" /&gt;</Value>
</Setting>
```

Whenever you add items to your Collection setting, the ListBox will also be updated.

Comment: Thank you very much Vitali. Very nice explanation. :)