# How to create an application settings parameter of type a list of structs?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, struct, application-settings

In my project I have a custom struct:

```cs
struct Point {
  public uint xPoint { get; }
  public uint yPoint { get; }

  public Point(uint x, uint y) {
    xPoint = x;
    yPoint = y;
  }
}
```

I'm using a list of these Points:

```
List<Point> pathToNavigate = new List<Point>();
```

What I'm trying to do is save a list of my Points to the Settings.settings:
[image: Like this]

I can't figure out how to change string to be a list of my struct Point.

I tried messing with the xml and manually add in my option but I can't work out how to do it. Most things I find tell me to use a custom namespace but I also can't get that working with a list of my Point struct.

Edit: My problem is with a custom struct using a list. The issue isn't adding the items to the list, it's being able to load their contents properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a List<string> on Settings.Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default).  Any custom objects needs to be marked `[Serializable]`, as `List<T>` is already.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't.

Comment: I'm able to save the items to my list. But when I try loading them after restarting the program it loads the amount of items in the list, but not the actual content of them. Each coordinate is always 0.

Comment: Your public properties need public setters.  See my answer for a complete solution including testing it actually works.  If you still have issues please post code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps below work.

However, I believe your issue is simply because `xPoint` and `yPoint` do not have public setters.  This is due to how `XmlSerializer`
works.  See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0).

First, create a setting.  In this case I named it `ListOfPoints`.  The type is irrelevant, we're going to change it anyways.

Manually edit "Settings.settings".  I just open it with Visual Studio's XML editor but use what you prefer.

Then change the **type** of the setting only.  Note you need to use HTML encoding for `<` and `>`.

**Entire Settings.settings:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="WindowsFormsApp1.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="ListOfPoints" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;WindowsFormsApp1.MyPoint&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

The only change made was this:

```
Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;WindowsFormsApp1.MyPoint&gt;"
```

**All Code:**

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyPoint
{
    public uint X { get; set; }
    public uint Y { get; set; }

    public MyPoint(uint x, uint y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is MyPoint))
            return false;
        var other = (MyPoint)obj;
        return other.X == X && other.Y == Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return unchecked(X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode());
    }
}

private static readonly List<MyPoint> saveMe = new List<MyPoint>();
private static List<MyPoint> loadMe;

private static void SaveData()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.ListOfPoints = saveMe;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private static void LoadData()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    loadMe = Properties.Settings.Default.ListOfPoints;
    TestData();
}

private static void TestData()
{
    if (loadMe.Count != saveMe.Count)
        throw new Exception("Different counts");
    for (int i = 0; i < loadMe.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!loadMe[i].Equals(saveMe[i]))
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(MyPoint)} at index {i} doesn't match");
    }
}
```

Test this by adding whatever you wish to `saveMe`.  Then run `SaveData` followed by `LoadData`.

`LoadData` will throw an exception if the data doesn't match.

Comment: So this is where I'm at currently. I'm able to match the count when loading my var. However, when I try to check the content of each point after loading, the value isn't being saved (or loaded?) for each point. When I first save it, I can see that `ListOfPoints[0].x` is 525. However, once I close and re-open the application it successfully loads in the proper count of ListOfPoints. BUT it doesn't save the x or y value. So when I check the value of my points it's `ListOfPoints.x` always being 0 when it should be 525.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes See the updated answer.  I missed the issue reading your code.  Try simply adding a public setter for your properties.  I added a settings reload to `LoadData` to test the application restart issue you mentioned.

Comment: You led me to the correct answer, thank you. The problem was `public uint xPoint { get; }` when it needed to be `public uint xPoint { get; set; }`. What a silly mistake that caused this massive headache.

Comment: Please comment on why the downvote so I can address any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the duplicate to your case (I can't flag it because I can't revote to close, and I post this answer to solve your difficulties as well as to be more precise and more complete than the various tutorials and duplicates):

[How to save a List<string> on Settings.Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default)

Having the serializable struct in for example the namespace below:

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{
  [Serializable]
  public struct Point
  {
    public uint xPoint { get; set; }
    public uint yPoint { get; set; }

    public Point(uint x, uint y)
    {
      xPoint = x;
      yPoint = y;
    }
  }
}
```

As mentionned previously, properties must be read-write, so I added auto-setters, and the struct must be serializable by adding the attrribute.

Compile the project.

You need to create a string parameter for example having the name `MyList` :

[image]

Then edit `Settings.settings` by hand using any text editor to change its type to:

```
System.Collections.Generic<WindowsFormsAppTest.Point>
```

In HTML text encoding like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;WindowsFormsAppTest.Point&gt;
```

> Settings.settings

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="MyList" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;WindowsFormsAppTest.Point&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

After saved, go to Visual Studio and reload the file, then you will be able to see the type is changed:

[image]

You need to update this settings generated C# code file using the designer by expanding the type of the parameter and to click on this custom list type:

[image]

If not, or in case of problem, you need to manually update these file:

> app.config to serializeAs Xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/></startup>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MyList" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

> Settings.Designer.cs to change the type of the property

```cs
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsAppTest.Point> MyList {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsAppTest.Point>)(this["MyList"]));
        }
```

Save all and/or compile again.

Now, you can write for example in the `Main` method or in the constructor of the main form or in the load event handler:

```
private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( Properties.Settings.Default.MyList == null )
    Properties.Settings.Default.MyList = new List<Point>();
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

And for example in a button click event handler:

```
private void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Add(new Point(10, 10));
  Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Add(new Point(10, 20));
  Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Add(new Point(20, 20));
  Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Add(new Point(50, 50));
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Now the config file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MyList" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfPoint xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <Point>
                            <xPoint>10</xPoint>
                            <yPoint>10</yPoint>
                        </Point>
                        <Point>
                            <xPoint>10</xPoint>
                            <yPoint>20</yPoint>
                        </Point>
                        <Point>
                            <xPoint>20</xPoint>
                            <yPoint>20</yPoint>
                        </Point>
                        <Point>
                            <xPoint>50</xPoint>
                            <yPoint>50</yPoint>
                        </Point>
                    </ArrayOfPoint>
                </value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsAppTest.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

To change one item we can write, because being a struct so a value-type:

```
private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var point = Properties.Settings.Default.MyList[0];
  point.xPoint = 100;
  point.yPoint = 100;
  Properties.Settings.Default.MyList[0] = point;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

And now the settings file has:

```xml
<Point>
    <xPoint>100</xPoint>
    <yPoint>100</yPoint>
</Point>
...
```

To test this, we can list the items using another button:

```
private void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var list = Properties.Settings.Default.MyList.Select(p => $"{p.xPoint}, {p.yPoint}");
  MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray()));
}
```

[image]

*Note*

To cleanup the application settings, you need to delete for example all these folders:

```
c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Organization\WindowsFormsAppTest.exe_Url_*
```

Where `Organization` and `WindowsFormsAppTest` comes from the manifest file defined in `AssemblyInfo.cs` using fields `AssemblyCompany` and `AssemblyTitle`.

Comment: This is a great post, however this is exactly where I'm already at with my problem. The issue is when I close the program and then open it I try to load those points. I get the result that `MyList.count = 4`. But when I check `MyList[0].xPoint` it always equals 0.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes If you don't set the properties writable and the struct serializable, it can't work.