# settings of list type not being saved

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a winforms app where you can get an overview of your project, by entering a description, name and image. I store those three different lists of strings and images, and then I tried to save it, but it doesn't work.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Name = new textList();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Description = new textList();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Image = new imageList();

        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Name.Add(item.Text);
        }
        foreach (var item in description)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Description.Add(item.Text);
        }
        foreach (var item in pictureBox)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Image.Add(item.BackgroundImage);
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

private void Oversigt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

        Properties.Settings.Default.Name = new textList();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Description = new textList();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Image = new imageList();
        foreach (var item in Properties.Settings.Default.Image)
        {
            var pic = new PictureBox();
            pic.Size = new Size(192, 108);
            pic.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
            pic.BackgroundImage = item;
            pic.Location = new Point(47, 209);
            Controls.Add(pic);
            pictureBox.Add(pic);
        }

        foreach(var item in Properties.Settings.Default.Name)
        {
            var name = new Label();
            name.AutoSize = true;
            name.Text = item;
            name.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 17);
            name.ForeColor = Color.White;
            Controls.Add(name);
            names.Add(name);
        }
        foreach(var item in Properties.Settings.Default.Description)
        {
            var desc = new Label();
            desc.AutoSize = false;
            desc.Size = new Size(192, 63);
            desc.Text = item;
            desc.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
            desc.ForeColor = Color.White;
            Controls.Add(desc);
            description.Add(desc);
        }
        arrangeProject();
    }

class textList : List<string>
{
}

class imageList : List<Image>
{
}
```

I tried making a setting that was just a normal string and that worked fine!
I also tried putting a breakpoint after save_Click, but I couldn't see anything there. Not sure if I did it right tho. I know there are version of the application, but that was set to 1.0.0.0 by default:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: See first duplicate for the correct way to save a generic list to the app settings. Note that it's a bit finicky to get right. See other duplicates for less-elegant but simpler workarounds.

Comment: I have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default . And been trying for a while to find out how to do it, so I just figured I'd ask myself.