# Cast StringCollection as List<int>

Tags: c#, casting

I have a `StringCollection` object being passed through a `ReportParameter` object, and I need to get it to be a `List<int>` instead.

So far, I've tried this

```
List<int> ids = (parameters != null) ? parameters[parameters.FindIndex(x => x.Name == "IDs")].Values.Cast<int>().ToList() : null;
```

Which should check if the parameters object is null, and if not it finds the index of the IDs parameter, and then tries to cast the values to a list of ints. I keep getting a `Cast is not valid` error. How would I go about converting the `StringCollection` to `List<int>` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201306/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listint has your solution

Comment: "Cast is not valid" is not valid error. Please post complete compiler error along with CSXXXX error code.

Comment: `List<string>` -> `List<int>` is covered in linked duplicate and the `StringCollection` -> `List<string>` covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844412/convert-stringcollection-to-liststring (combine/refactor as needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are string values, you can't cast string to `int`. You need to `Convert/Parse` it like:

```
parameters[parameters.FindIndex(x => x.Name == "IDs")].Values
                     .Cast<String>() //So that LINQ could be applied
                     .Select(int.Parse)
                     .ToList()
```

You need `.Cast<String>()` so that you can apply LINQ on the `StringCollection`.