# Join StringCollection with commas

Tags: c#, stringcollection

Usually, joining a List with commas is easy using string.Join(). However, coming across a StringCollection today, string.Join() outputs "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" output instead of a comma-separated string.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestJoin()
    {
        StringCollection stringCollection = new StringCollection() { "Denis", "Jason", "Shawn" };
        // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException:
        // 'Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Denis, Jason, Shawn>. Actual:<System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>.'
        Assert.AreEqual("Denis, Jason, Shawn", string.Join(", ", stringCollection));
    }
```

How do we Join() a StringCollection?

Comment: This is not quite correct. if sc is a StringCollection object, string.Join(", ", sc) will call `ToString` on this object which yields "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" (because ToString is not overridden in StringCollection). Therefore the result of string.Join will be the string "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection"

Comment: `string.Join() creates a StringCollection output` no it doesn't. It always returns a `string`. Post your code. You're probably not calling the method you think you are

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Klaus' deduction is correct. See the quick unit test I hadn't bothered to post.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to convert the StringCollection to a List collection first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/844420/4682228.

```
var commaSeparatedList = string.Join(", ", stringCollection.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToList` since `string.Join` has an overload that takes `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: To expand on this answer: The reason you need to write `.Cast<string>()` is because `string.Join()` is expecting an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a plain `IEnumerable`. The `.Cast<string>()` converts an `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<string>`. That is the specific job of [`IEnumerable.Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-6.0)