# foreach loop repeats result of searchresult resultpropertycollection more than once in a list of 31 users

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, ldap, ldap-query

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
            "LDAP://123.45.678.9:389/cn=TestGroup,ou=Groups,dc=test,dc=test2", 
            "uid=test_user, ou=test, dc=test,dc=test2", "test-abc", 
            AuthenticationTypes.None);

        // List<string> GroupMembers = new List<string>() { "first_last", "first_last" };
        StringCollection GroupMembers = new StringCollection();
        Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        Console.WriteLine("login success");

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uniqueMember");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        search.Filter = "(&(uniqueMember=*))";

        //SearchResultCollection resultCollection = search.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
        {
            ResultPropertyCollection resultProperty = result.Properties;

            foreach (string GroupMemberDN in resultProperty["uniqueMember"])
            {
                DirectoryEntry directoryMember = new DirectoryEntry(
                    "LDAP://123.45.678.9:389/" + GroupMemberDN, 
                    "uid=test_user, ou=test, dc=test2,dc=test3", "test-abc", 
                    AuthenticationTypes.None);

                PropertyCollection DirectoryMemberProperties = directoryMember.Properties;
                GroupMembers.Add(directoryMember.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
                GroupMembers.GetEnumerator();

                foreach (string member in GroupMembers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(member);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

the `foreach` loop repeats result of searchresult / resultpropertycollection more than once in a list of 31 users, such that the printed result in console is about 60-70 users, repeated a few times

for example:

```
test_user1@email.com
test_user1@email.com
test_user2@email.com
test_user3@email.com
test_user4@email.com
test_user5@email.com
test_user6@email.com
test_user7@email.com
test_user8@email.com
test_user9@email.com
test_user1@email.com
test_user1@email.com
test_user2@email.com
// and so on so forth in this pattern..
```

I'd just to retrieve the 31 users assigned in uniqueMembers of the cn=TestGroup to be printed once like with Console.WriteLine(

Everytime I run the Program, it works (yes) but not correctly.

Comment: FYI, `List<string>` is favored now over `StringCollection`. You can read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669106/best-string-container-stringcollection-collectionstring-liststring-array) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you're outputting the entire `GroupMembers` collection on each iteration of both the other two `foreach` loops.

Instead we should move the code that outputs the `GroupMembers` information to the console **after** the outer `foreach` loop (after you've finished populating it).

```
foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
{
    ResultPropertyCollection resultProperties = result.Properties;

    foreach (string groupMemberDN in resultProperties["uniqueMember"])
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryMember = new DirectoryEntry(
            "LDAP://123.45.678.9:389/" + groupMemberDN, 
            "uid=test_user, ou=test, dc=test2,dc=test3", "test-abc", 
            AuthenticationTypes.None);

        GroupMembers.Add(directoryMember.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
    }
}

// Now that our collection is fully populated, output it to the console
foreach (string member in GroupMembers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member);
}
```